# Exporting cross-sectional data from NetLogo Behavior Space

Tags: netlogo, export-to-csv

I have created an experiment in Behavior Space for my NetLogo model. I would like to save the value of some variables for each individual turtle, later to be processed with statistical software (Stata or R). My first attempt at a reporter was:

```
[my-variable] of turtles
```

This kind of works, but the formatting of the resulting CSV file is problematic. All values for an individual variable are stored in a space-separated list:

```
"run", "[my-variable] of turtles"
"1", "[48.234967724191584, 15.361986575058953, 19.613022950636537, ... ]"
...
```

What I would like:

```
"run", "[my-variable] of turtle_0", "[my-variable] of turtle_1", ...
"1", "48.234967724191584", "15.361986575058953", ... ]"
...
```

I am looking for something like the `split()` method in Python. Any suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE: Cross-sectional analysis is predicated on the assumption that, during the same run of the model, all reporters list turtles-own variables *in the same order*. So, if I have two reporters:

```
[my-variable-1] of turtles => "[1 2]"
[my-variable-2] of turtles => "[3 4]"
```

I need to be sure that both reporters take turtles in the same order, so that turtle 0 has `my-variable-1` equal to `1` and `my-variable-2`equal to `3`, whereas turtle 1 has `my-variable-1` equal to `2` and `my-variable-2`equal to `4`. I cannot find a mention of this in the NetLogo documentation. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an answer to the latter part of your question.  `[my-variable-1] of turtles` will give you the values of my-variable-1 in random order as `of` takes the agents in random order.  (This is documented at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/dictionary.html#O).

If you want a fixed order by who number, then you can use `sort` and `map`.

`map [[my-variable-1] of ?] sort turtles`

`sort turtles` creates a sorted list of turtles and then that list is given to the `map' primitive to create the list of values ordered by the who number of the turtle.  Of course you'd need be careful that no turtles die or are created during the run.

As for the writing of the observations to a CSV file, there are other posts that look at that specifically.  You might also want to look at the stats extension to see if that would help by allowing you to write out all the results at the end of the run from a list of lists that is easily handled by the CSV extension.

Charles